# How to remove unmet dependencies from Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I run dpkg --list 'linux-image*' I can see following list:

```
un  linux-image                          <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.0                      <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic        3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-77-generic        3.16.0-77.99~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic         4.4.0-59.80~14.04.1     amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic         4.4.0-75.96~14.04.1     amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic         4.4.0-78.99~14.04.2     amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic         4.4.0-79.100~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic         4.4.0-81.104~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic         4.4.0-87.110~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
**in  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic         <none>                  amd64                   (no description available)**
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic  3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1    amd64                   Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

When I try to remove using below command I am getting error 
command  sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic

error:

```
vf-root@vfroot-ThinkPad-T440:~$ **sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic**
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for vf-root: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic but it is not going to be installed
**E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**
```

even I run this apt-get -f install command I get this similar error for linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic

In the dpkg --list 'linux-image*'  list I can see this linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic image uninstalled .. Remove Purge all these commands are not working, can anyone please give me any solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for debugging `dpkg` problems, 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get autoremove
```

and continue to delete packages, these 2 commands should help

Comment: when I run "apt-get -f install" command I face following error    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-89-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-89-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)